# Dynamically populated android layout with items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

I have a case where I would like to dynamically populate a layout with view set to match parent at equal weight, in a horizontal fashion.

I don't want the view to be scrollable, and the case will never arise where all the items are not able to fit.

But if the number of items should always be evenly spaced withing the root layout.

Each individual item will be a layout containing a check box and text view.

I am not certain if this case is suited to ListView, or if it is only intended for fixed size items, that can exceeds bounds of parent.

Is the proper way to do this, to create and xml layout for single item, and then dynamically inflate n amount of those layouts into the parent layout?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

If you are certain that that all the items will always be able to fit, then just use a listview.   This will give you the advantages of an adapter view.

disable the scrollbar with

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```

you can even, if you must disable scrolling by extending ListView and adding

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
   if(ev.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
      return true;
   return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Or you can just use a LinearLayout and add views programatically using

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
layout.addView(newView, index);
```

But I would probably just use a ListView or RecyclerView and let it behave normally.  This will cover you for anyone using a very small device.

Comment: If i use listview will it evenly space the items out such that they use up all the room evenly?

Comment: ah, use a linearlayout with weights.  if you set layout_width to 0dp and set the layout_weight for each of the items to 1, the available width will be shared equally between the items.